# How to prove this Sobolev inequality?

Tags: partial-differential-equations, sobolev-spaces, holder-inequality, poissons-equation

$$
\Vert uv\Vert_{H^m} \leq C\sum_{j=2}^m \Vert u\Vert_{H_j} \Vert v\Vert_{H^{m-j+2}}, m\geq 2$$
This inequality from

*Auzinger, Winfried; Kassebacher, Thomas; Koch, Othmar; Thalhammer, Mechthild*, [**Convergence of a strang splitting finite element discretization for the Schrödinger-Poisson equation**](https://doi.org/10.1051/m2an/2016059), ESAIM, Math. Model. Numer. Anal. 51, No. 4, 1245-1278 (2017). [ZBL1379.65071](https://zbmath.org/?q=an:1379.65071).

This paper said

> By the Hölder inequality and the Sobolev embeddings of $H^2$ in $L^\infty$ and $H^1$ in $L^4$ , we have$$
> \Vert uv\Vert_{H^m} \leq C\sum_{j=2}^m \Vert u\Vert_{H_j} \Vert v\Vert_{H^{m-j+2}}, m\geq 2$$

I don't konw how to prove this inequality.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

By Leibniz formula, $\nabla^n(uv)$ will give you terms of the form $\nabla^k u \nabla^{n-k}v$ with $0\leq k\leq n$. Then if $k<m$ and $n-k< m$, you use the following Holder inequality
$$
\|\nabla^k u \nabla^{n-k}v\|_{L^2} \leq \|\nabla^ku\|_{L^4} \|\nabla^{n-k}v\|_{L^4}
$$
and so the mentioned Sobolev embedding gives
$$
\|\nabla^k u \nabla^{n-k}v\|_{L^2} \leq \|u\|_{H^{k+1}} \|v\|_{H^{n-k+1}}
$$
which is in the range of the sum. If $n-k=m$, so $k=0$ and $n=m$, then you do not want to get any $H^{m+1}$ appearing, so you write instead
$$
\|u \nabla^{m}v\|_{L^2} \leq \|u\|_{L^\infty} \|\nabla^mv\|_{L^2}
$$
and so the other mentioned Sobolev embedding gives
$$
\| u \nabla^{m}v\|_{L^2} \leq \|u\|_{H^{2}} \|v\|_{H^{m}}
$$
which again is bounded by the sum. The same applies to the case $k=n=m$.